# How to respond to password prompt with StartProcess?

Tags: interoperability, external-calls, process-control

Title says it all so let me show it on a Git example on Windows.

Let's say you have your git executable on the system `PATH`:

```
KillProcess @ process;    

process = StartProcess[$SystemShell];

WriteLine[ process, "cd path\\to\\repository\\directory"];
WriteLine[ process, "git status"];
WriteLine[ process, "git push origin master"];

Pause[.1];
processString = ReadString[process, EndOfBuffer]
```

> "Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.10240]
>
> (c) 2015 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.
>
> C:\Users\Kuba\Documents> cd path\to\repository\directory
>
> C:\path\to\repository\directory>git status
>
> On branch master
>    Your branch is ahead of 'origin/master' by 1 commit.
>     (use "git push" to publish your local commits)
>   (......)
>
> C:\path\to\repository\directory > git push origin master
>   "

So in the terminal I'd get the response:

> Password for (remote.repo):_

Here I have no visible response. Is it possible to proceed?

Comment: I'm not sure it is related, but when we use remote kernel in Mathematica, it also requires the user to input password. And it seems to use Java to popup the window and get the user password.

Comment: Maybe you can try powershell, which I believe can be programly manipulated with NETLink.

Comment: Have you explored the possibility of supplying the password separately? [Example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28562679/395258).

Comment: @Pickett not yet but I know it is there, the question is meant to be more general than git push only.

Comment: I would expect the process to just wait for the password on stdin. Have you tried to just `WriteLine[process,password]` after the Pause? It might well be that git behaves slightly different when it recognizes it isn't connected to a terminal on stdin (which I assume is what is happening in the background) and just doesn't send a prompt in that case...

Comment: @AlbertRetey Yes I tried that but to no avail.

Answer (score 2):

I ran into a similar issue on a mac when trying to install some compiled code. This code prompts the user for a password if asked:

```
(*------   Needs admin priviliges!!!
- no tty or askpass program available through StartProcess[]
--------*)
Print["Installing..."];
WriteLine[myShell,"sudo -S true"];Pause[1]; (* asks for password...*)
WriteLine[myShell,"wrongPass"];(* use to get a reply*) 

(* If already authenticated we get 'cmd not found' *)
While[  
  passAttemps < 3
, shellSE = TimeConstrained[ 
    ReadLine[ProcessConnection[myShell,"StandardError"]]
  , 1
  ]
; While[
    !(shellSE === $Aborted) (* False when ReadLine times out *)
  , Print[shellSE]
  ; askPass = If[
      StringContainsQ[shellSE,"try again"]
    , 1
    , 0
    ]
  ; shellSE = TimeConstrained[ 
      ReadLine[ProcessConnection[myShell,"StandardError"]]
    , 1
    ];
  ]
; If[
    askPass == 1
  , tmpPass = Input["Password",,FieldMasked->True]
  ; askPass = 0;
    (*Else, askPass == 0 *)
  , Break[];
  ]
; WriteLine[myShell, ToString @ tmpPass ] 
; Pause[1]
; passAttemps++;
];
```

--- Updated the code after finding out about a new sudo command:

I've since discovered a new sudo command that let me change the code to:

```
myShell = StartProcess[$SystemShell]; Pause[1];
WriteLine[myShell, "sudo -n true"];
shellSE = TimeConstrained[ReadLine[ProcessConnection[myShell,"StandardError"]], 2];
If[StringContainsQ[shellSE, "Password is required"], 
 Print["Needs sudo password to install..."]; askPass = 1;
 WriteLine[myShell, "sudo -S true"]; Pause[2]; (* asks for password...*)
While[passAttemps < 3,
   If[askPass == 1, 
    ChoiceDialog[Panel[Row[{
        "Password: ", 
        InputField[Dynamic[tmpPass], String, FieldMasked -> True]
        }], FrameMargins -> 8, ImageMargins -> 5], 
     WindowSize -> {250, 140}, WindowTitle -> "Enter password"
     ];
    WriteLine[myShell, ToString@tmpPass] ; Pause[1]; passAttemps++;,
    Break[]  (* If we have the right password, 
    Break While loop *)
    ];

   (* See if input password was accepted *)
   shellSE = 
    TimeConstrained[
     ReadLine[ProcessConnection[myShell, "StandardError"]], 2];
   If[shellSE === $Aborted, shellSE = "Password accepted"]; 
   Print[StringReplace[shellSE, "Password:" -> ""]];
   askPass = If[StringContainsQ[shellSE, "try again"], 1, 0];
   ] (* End of passAttemps <3 *)];
```

Answer (score 1):

I failed to use `RunProcess` and friends even after I set `SSH` with empty passphrase for my test repository.

I don't know how to proceed this way but maybe someone is interested in the work around I'm using.

I'm using Batch file (I'm working on Windows, sorry). With a little help of MMA templates system, which is not necessary but I find it convenient.

So the simplest case, we have

> ../PackageDevelopementDir (*contains*)
>
> |- PackageDir
>
> |- Package.nb
>
> |- pushTemplate.tr

When I'm happy with edits and I want to push I'm running following code which is somewhere in `Package.nb`:

```
SetDirectory@NotebookDirectory[];
FileTemplateApply[
  Import["pushTemplate.tr"],
  <|
   "commitMessage" -> "templatePush"
   |>,
  "temp.bat"
  ] // SystemOpen
```

This creates a .bat files and runs it, so the cmd should apprear and you can commit push or whatever. At the end of the file is a script that deletes it.

Here's the content of the template file:

> echo off
>
> git --version
>
> SET GIT_DIR=%~dp0.git
>   SET GIT_WORK_TREE=%~dp0
>
> git status
>
> echo will add. and commit now
>
> pause >nul
>
> git add .
>
> git commit -m "`commitMessage`"
>
> git status
>
> echo will push now
>
> pause >nul
>
> git push origin master
>
> echo let me die now...
>
> pause >nul
>
> (goto) 2>nul & del "%~f0"